# WTForms stores wrong password hash

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, passlib

I'm using [WTForms-Alchemy](http://wtforms-alchemy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to define forms from model objects. I defined a field as a password thus:

`password = db.Column(PasswordType(schemes=['pbkdf2_sha512']), nullable=True)`

I persist the form to PostgreSQL and I always end up with the wrong hash in the database. Interestingly, this method worked flawlessly on a previous project that used MySQL.

I've now decided to encrypt my passwords by hand by calling `pbkdf2_sha512.encrypt` and `pbkdf2_sha512.verify` manually and the hashes are stored correctly.

Am I missing a configuration parameter? Could this be a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what the issue here is, but I wanted to mention that using pbkdf2 is not recommended now-a-days -- if you're storing user password hashes you should preferably be storing passwords using bcrypt. bcrypt is a cpu hard hashing algorithm, which makes it much harder to brute force for potential attackers.

Comment: Do you have a link for that?

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/do-any-security-experts-recommend-bcrypt-for-password-storage